# Refreshing Page in Opera using Ajax

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, opera

I am trying to refresh the content of a page (which contains two gridviews) in Opera, version 12.12. It seems that my page blocks in some intermediary point because it remains blank. My code works perfectly in all browsers except for Opera:

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "refresh", "<script type='text/javascript'>function refreshList() { try { if (document.all) { document.all('" + lbnRefreshList.ClientID + "').click(); } else { document.getElementById('" + lbnRefreshList.ClientID + "').click(); } } catch(e){} } </script>");

protected void lbnRefreshList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // redind data to gridviews
}
```

I am also using an ajax Update panel and my gridviews are inside the panel, while lbnRefreshList is set as an AsyncPostback trigger. However, I have no idea why my page is not refreshing on Opera, despite the fact that the code executes. I am prompted with a blank white page instead.

Any advice much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please show and the rest of aspx page code, and clear the script that you try to run after the update.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me that the "click" event is never triggered on Opera for somehow reason , did you try to use jQuery? their framework tries to be compatible with all browser,

you can try to do something like

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

function refreshList() { 
 $('#" + lbnRefreshList.ClientID + "').click();
}

</script>
```